# What is the linguistic name of /p͡r/?

Tags: phonology, phonetics

I am creating a language called Knashta, and one of the phonemes is /p͡r/.

I believe this sound would be a trilled affricate, and I'm guessing that it's name would be a voiceless bilabial alveolar trill.

Am I right or wrong?

Comment: Affricates must have a fricative as the second component, your /p͡r/ doesn't have one, so it's not an affricate.

Comment: A trilled affricate is not a regular affricate. It begins with a stop and ends with a trill. An example would be [mbʙ], the voiced prenasalized trilled bilabial affricate. If you don't like the term affricate, you can also call it a  'post-trilled consonant'

Comment: Still, [ʙ] is a trilled _fricative_. And I like the term affricate, only it doesn't fit your sound.

Comment: The term [*trilled affricate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilled_affricate) is used in literature, whether or not we like it as fitting this type of sound.

Answer (score 1):

As it happens, there is a model of speech production -- the Convertor-Distributor Model (*Phonetica* 57:128-38) -- advocated by Osamu Fujimura, which denies that there is ordering of elements in a syllable position such as "onset". To handle clusters like [pr], the model has bigger inventory of "segments", so [pr] would be a voiceless labial alveolar trill (assuming a trilled *r*). I don't agree with the model, but the point is that your proposal corresponds to something that exists in linguistic theory.

Answer (score -3):

This is a cluster.

What constitutes *affricates* and the like, well it's not part of this arrangement. Anything like this trying to be incorporated in a nomenclature like affricate is serving two masters. Which is bad. Creating a language *still* falls within the parameters of the research Chomsky presented in grammar, phonology, and phonetics. What's more - a language that is so called created is *not* and *never* a natural language and does not stem from the natural development **all languages follow to the latter**.

Comment: This question isn't about the merit of constructed languages. Also, please don't use caps. It's not necessary.

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics SE, Messiah! I fail to see how your contribution answers the question. Do you think you can make that clearer?